# How to concatenate many SQL rows into single text string for int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The SQL table I have is as follows:

```
ID     Name   NameID 
1      John   1
1      Dan    2
1      Jill   3
2      Jack   4
2      Sam    5
```

I need this table to be like this:

```
ID      Name             NameID 
1       John, Dan, Jill  1, 2, 3
2       Jack, Sam        4, 5
```

The SQL query that I have for now is as follows:

```
SELECT ID, 
    STUFF((
        SELECT N', ' + Name 
        FROM Table2 b 
        WHERE b.NameID = a.NameID 
        FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'
        ),1,2,N'') AS Name,
    NameID
FROM Table1 a
```

That query does what I need for the Name column but it won't work when I try to do it for the `NameID` column. I need all the cells that have `int` to remain as `int`. I cannot have them as `string` since I will be needing to filter the table by the `NameID`. How do I get all `NameID` into a single cell for each `ID`?

Comment: let me get this straight, you want to concatenate some `int` values onto a single column, but you want them to remain as `int`s?

Comment: You will have to cast/convert them to varchar so they are treated as strings. After that you could probably do what you did for the Name column to get it to work.

Comment: If you want to concatenate NameIDs as a list separated by comma, you may agree with me, that a comma separated list of integers is not an integer.

Comment: `I need all the cells that have int to remain as int` - Why? What good will it do to keep the column type as int (which is not possible)? Could you execute math operation on it or add them together or something else (rhetorical question, answer is no). Those are reasons to keep a value numeric. Now for the sake of argument lets assume it is possible, a concatenated list of ints in a single cell is useless in sql, you can't do anything with it or materialize it out of sql (lets say to an ORM).

Comment: Because I have a asp.net application that has a drop down list with the `Name`s and `NameID`s and when a user chooses an option, it will filter the grid with above information by the `NameID`. If there is a way to still filter by `NameID` and have it as a string, then please show me how. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, asp.net will also expects the value of a list item in a drop down to be a string. Have you tried casting it to a varchar and then doing the same thing you did with name?

Comment: I've tried that, the issue is (using the example above) that if I search for `John`, it will give me only the rows with just `John`. If it has `John` and other names, then it will not show up.

Comment: I think you are looking for STUFF and CONCAT. You will simply need to convert to varchar to store, and convert back to int when you need them again.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,

    STUFF((
        SELECT N', ' + Name 
        FROM Table1 b 
        WHERE b.ID = a.ID 
        FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'
        ),1,2,N'') AS Name,

    STUFF((
        SELECT N', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), NameID) 
        FROM Table1 b 
        WHERE b.ID = a.ID 
        FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'
        ),1,2,N'') AS NameID

FROM Table1 a
```